# Is one-way ANOVA + Tukey HSD a good choice for significant test for data with different orders of magnitude?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, p-value, tukey-hsd-test

I'm here to receive some information regarding the application of a statistical test of significance for this type of data.

The example shows the values ​​of the peak areas of a given cocoa molecule for 4 defect level groups:

Group A: 100% defect ;
Group B: 10% defect ;
Group C: 1% defect ;
Group D: 0% defect ;

[image]

I immediately thought of applying a one-way ANOVA with post-hoc TUKEY HSD to evaluate the inter-
group differences and the result was:

- p-value < 0.05 = 4.5086e-13

Tukey's test HSD:

- no significant differences C (1%) vs D (0%) => p-value= 0.6423331 (yes significant differences for all others)

So I thought of doing a one-way Anova only between C and D and this test has now highlighted significant differences (p-value <0.05 = 2.0511e-07) between these 2 groups.

Therefore, I fear that the statistical tool used in this case is incorrect because it cannot be assumed that the variances between the groups are homogeneous, since there are orders of magnitude different between one group considered and another which affect the result.

I would like to kindly ask you what might be the most valid alternative to carry out a test of this type on this experiment.

Or could a transformation of the data i.e. logarithm help?

Thank you so much for your support,

Francesco

Comment: A log transformation might help, or a test that doesn't assume homogeneity of variance, like Welch's anova.